# Android screen blackout when storing thousands of records in realm

Tags: android, realm

So I am getting thousands of records from the server via API, and storing them to my realm database, all these things(fetching data & storing to the realm) done in the background thread, but those thousands of records require a lot of memory that causes device's screen to blackout.

This is what I have done:

To parse data:

```
 val listOfProduct=fromJsonTo<List<Product>>("products") // here mapping JsonArray to List<Produtc> 
 listOfProduct.saveToRealmForMobileSync(realm) // This will save List<Product> to realm
```

For converting JsonArray into List:

```
inline fun <reified T> JsonObject.fromJsonTo(key:String):T?{
    return if (has(key))
        gson.fromJson<T>(getAsJsonArray(key).toString(), object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type)
    else
        null
}
```

To save List into realm:

```
fun <T> List<T>?.saveToRealmForMobileSync(realm: Realm) where T: RealmObject {
    if (this==null)
        return
    realm.executeTransaction {
        it.insertOrUpdate(this)
    }
}
```

So this code works fine with limited data but when I need to store a huge amount of data into the realm, it shows the black screen for 4 to 5 seconds, but no ANR no crash occurs, just a black screen and user can't do anything. So the question is how to avoid this blackout issue?

If anyone knows any other suitable or better approach that would also help.